# Retrieving an int's binary value, outputting the ASCII the binary corresponds to

Tags: c, binary

Not really sure how to word this.
I have the int 'value' = 121, which is 1111001 in binary.
1111001 from binary to ASCII = "y"

I was wondering how I can convert the int value 121 to be printed as an ASCII character. Is there a built in function in C to do this?

Comment: `printf("%c\n", 121);`

Comment: There aren't many built-in functions in C, but there are library functions to do the job.  You could use `putchar(121);` or `fputc(121, stdout);` or `printf("%c\n", 121);` (which outputs a newline too, unlike the previous ones), `fprintf(stdout, "%c\n", 121);`.  You could do the job with `fwrite()` too, but you'd have to be rather careful - you've already got enough options that you don't need that one too.

Comment: Peter Varo's answer did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Code I wrote earlier for someone else's question and adapted to your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int nr_to_binary = 0;

  printf("Number: ");
  scanf("%d", &nr_to_binary);

  int i = (sizeof(nr_to_binary) * 8);

  for(; i > 0  ; i--)
  {
    printf("%d", (nr_to_binary >> (i - 1)) & 1);
  }

  printf("\n\nASCII value of %d is %c", nr_to_binary, nr_to_binary);

  return 0;
}
```

Result

```
Number: 121
00000000000000000000000001111001

ASCII value of 121 is y
```

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't write `for (int i = sizeof(nr_to_binary) * 8; i > 0; i--)` since you clearly have C99 support if you use the declaration for `i` where it is.  Theoretically, you should use `<limits.h>` and `CHAR_BIT` instead of `8`, but that's a really minor nitpick.  It would be sensible to check that `scanf()` succeeded.  If the use types `hello` instead of a number, it is better not to convert a quasi-random number instead.